# Change the UI in function of instruction

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to show an image when i'm connected to the server(i'm developping a SIP application).
I've made this(created an XML file[connected.xml] with a textview and an image), but have a FC:

```
public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                        updateStatus("Registered to server.");
                        Log.d("SUCCEED","Registration DONE");
                        setContentView(R.layout.connected);
                      }
```

I want then add an image when connecting and disconnected...
How can i solve this problem ?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <ImageView android:id="@+id/disconnected" android:src="@drawable/disconnected" android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:gravity="center"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <ImageView android:id="@+id/connected" android:src="@drawable/connected" android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:gravity="center"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `setContentView` multiple times in one activity, unless you are 100% sure that you've cleaned up everything in it. 
Even then, your users might find strange, that pressing the back button they won't see what they were waiting, though starting the same activity.

So you should rather think about

- changing your views' visibility to
  show/hide different parts of it, or
- a more elegant and easier solution:
  use a `ViewFlipper`.

**Update 1**
Here is a sample usage of the `ViewFlipper`:
put these lines in your layout xml:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- your first view comes here -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- your second view comes here -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

and in your java code, when you need to change the view, you write:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flipper.showNext();
```

**Extra**:
You can animate your flipping, all you have to do is set the `in` and `out` animation of your `flipper` before calling `showNext` or `showPrevious`:

```
Animation inAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f, 
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
inAnimation.setDuration(250);
inAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

Animation outAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
outAnimation.setDuration(250);
outAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flipper.setInAnimation(inAnimation);
flipper.setOutAnimation(outAnimation);
flipper.showNext();
```

**Update 2**:

A sample for `ViewFlipper` with global header:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/status_text" android:text="Status: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" android:layout_below="@id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <!-- your first view comes here without the status TextView -->
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <!-- your second view comes here -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @rekaszeru: i'm really loving this ViewFlipper! Have you please a guide that i can follow ? Thank you very much.

Comment: please see my update for a sample usage of the `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Well, i just can thank you for this awesome answer. Edit your second relativelayout with this comment  <!-- your second view comes here --> (second not first ;) ) .anyway, thak you very much.

Comment: :)) thanks, @androniennn! that's the problem with copy-paste. it does not know what i'm thinking...

Comment: @rekaszeru: i need your help: i've maked like this answer, but i have a textview that i want it to always shows! when the next view appears the textview is gone(i want it to show the status of the connection as the first view does), it has the same id ! any help please ?

Comment: You should remove that textview from the `ViewFlipper`, and it will be always visible.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Sorry but the first element that i have is <ViewFlipper>. I put the textview lonely in a relativelayout ?

Comment: You mean in your `layout.xml` the root is the `ViewFlipper` element? Then you should encapsulate it inside an other layout, and move the global `TextView` near the `ViewFlipper`. I'll update my answer with a small sample in several minutes.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Exactly. Thank you very much. Will wait for the update :).

Comment: @rekaszeru: It worked but just one little problem: the textview is well displayed in the second view but not in the first one(the image takes the place of the textview)! Please see my edited first answer.Thank you very much.

Comment: You should specify the `layout_below` attribute on the `ViewFlipper`, not on the images! `<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a thread problem: UI changes must happen on the Activity's main loop thread. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html:

1. Create a Handler for the activity.
2. Send a Message (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) when the registration is done.
3. In the Handler, receive that message and make your UI change.

Let me know how that works.

EDIT: fixed the message link

Comment: But as rekaszeru said, i can't change the UI in one activity... ?